# How to customize XLV

Tags: publishing-site, development, xlv

On the first page of our web app we want some "boxes" with a image and some links.
What is the best approach for this?
My first guess is to render data from a custom list.
For this I need very custom HTML, is XLV a good solution?

I had a look at [sharepoint-2010-list-view-blog-series-part-3-list-view-architecture](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2010/02/25/sharepoint-2010-list-view-blog-series-part-3-list-view-architecture.aspx), but I'm not quite sure how to do this.
If I use designer I won't get any usable XSL, if I edit it I will get tons of XSL I don't need. I just need a basic example of how I can render my fields within simple HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an XLV (the new name for the DVWP) you'll have total formatting freedom and the ability to use whatever DataSource you want.  My suggestion would be to start with an XLV which only displays the Title for the list and work on the XSL from there (if you want to avoid the "tons of XSL I don't need").

My eBook (or the underlying blog series) can help you with the XSL.

Comment: If I could start from scratch that would be the best. But I'm not sure where to start.
I just found out how I can set designer to show all the XSL, so i have a starting point with all the data. I probably need to read up on basic XSL

Comment: http://www.sympraxisconsulting.com/Unlocking-the-Mysteries-of-the-SharePoint-Data-View-Web-Part-XSL-Tags.aspx

Comment: For the record, XLV is not the new name for DVWP, these are two different Web Parts both available in SP 2010.

Comment: You're totally right, Christophe. Back in May I didn't know enough about it!

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this method:

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/05/28/html-calculated-column-solutions-for-sp-2010-part-ii/

Here is how it works:

- you use a calculated column to create your HTML string. My example displays a chart, in your case you'll need "img" and "a" tags.
- in SharePoint Designer, edit the XLV Web Part and disable output escaping for the calculated column. Then the cc will render as HTML.